# Jquery UI calendar show mysql dates?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, calendar

I need to get a series of dates from a mysql database using php, once I query the database and have all my dates as a result of the query, is it then possible to show those dates in for example red on the jquery UI calendar?

Comment: Use the [`beforeShowDay` event](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay). See [this tutorial](http://stevethomas.com.au/jquery/jquery-datepicker-ajax-request-to-highlight-days-from-mysql.html) for more information on how to do this from mysql database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that should help you.
Here's a link to a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/tiborkiray/EXGW4/

CSS:

```
td.colorRed a {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
         // apply your logic in here
         if (date == yourDate) {
              return [true, 'colorRed', 'ToolTip'];
          }
          return [true, '', 'ToolTip'];
       }
});
```

The function beforeShowDay takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with [0] equal to true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable, [1] equal to a CSS class name(s) or "" for the default presentation, and [2] an optional popup tooltip for this date. It is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

You should make the dates from server side (MySql) available on the client side. Once you have those dates add them to the beforeShowDay logic. In javascript new Date(unix_timestamp*1000); will convert your server side timestamp into one that javascript can consume (1000 is to go from seconds to miliseconds)

Comment: I also want to show past dates as highlighted, its going to be use to show posts so I can look at the calender and easily see all the posts by date. Would the method above also show past dates?

Comment: It should work just fine on past dates 
td.colorRed a{
    color: #FF0000 !important;
}

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to a working version http://jsfiddle.net/tiborkiray/EXGW4/

Comment: The bit that's still got me a little confused is which bit is making the selected dated the mysql dates?

Comment: if (date == yourDate) { \n
yourDate is the mysql date as I understand